# How to constrain a View's Width to its Height?

Tags: maui

In my ContentPage, I have a Grid that holds two Views, a Border, and another Grid. My goal is to get the Border to be a perfect square by taking up as much vertical space as it can, and then to constrain its Width to its Height. My xaml looks like this;

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Border x:Name="myBorder" Grid.Column="0" />
    <Grid Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

On Android, I was able to hook into the OnMeasure() method of the ContentPage, and successfully assign the Width like this:

```
protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
{
    base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);

    // Make the border a square that fills the space
    myBorder.WidthRequest = myBorder.Height;
}
```

However, on iOS, the Height is -1, which doesn't work. I'm unsure how to solve this. Xamarin.Forms had a RelativeLayout, but no such layout exists in MAUI and it looks like it never will be because they figured all potential issues could be solved with a Grid. However, I'm not sure how I could solve this using a Grid's layout tools. Any ideas?

I've tried reading the Height of my Border at various different times (including at a point where it would definitely have a measured Height) and it's always -1.

Comment: Did you try binding the Border's Width to the parent Grid's Actual Height?

Comment: `Border` expects to have another element as its child. What happens if you use `BoxView` instead?

Comment: The Border does have a child, I just didn't include it here as it wasn't important to the question. The Border should be getting its Height from the containing Grid, not its child. To be clear, I'm using ColumnDefinitions, not RowDefinitions in the containing Grid.

Comment: @o_w, I did not. That could be a potential solution. If you can confirm it works, please post an answer.

Comment: @o_w, I confirmed that binding the Width to the Height with a relative binding works. I'm not sure how, but there must be some internal way it's measuring height that isn't exposed the way I'm imagining. If you post an answer, I will accept it. Good idea, by the way. I never thought of trying that before you suggested it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try binding the Border's Width to its parent Grid's actual height:

```
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Border x:Name="myBorder"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        WidthRequest="{Binding Height, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}}"/>
                <Grid Grid.Column="1" />
            </Grid>
```

Comment: In my instance, I was able to bind directly to the Border's Height, but this is what led me to the answer. Thank you.