# Border in layout does not stretch to bottom

Tags: maui

In my .NET MAUI App I use a border within a Grid

```xml
<ContentView.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="BorderStyleView" TargetType="Border">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource White}" />
            <Setter Property="StrokeShape" Value="RoundRectangle 10, 10, 10, 10" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="15" />
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.9" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="Start"/>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="CollectionViewStyle" TargetType="CollectionView">
            <Setter Property="IsGrouped" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Always" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10, 5, 10, 15" />
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentView.Resources>


<Grid>

    <Image Source="backgroundimage.png" Aspect="AspectFill" />
    <Grid BackgroundColor="Transparent">
        <Grid.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1">
                <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0.1" />
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1.0" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Grid.Background>
    </Grid>

    <Grid Background="Green">
        <Border x:Name="InnerBorder" Style="{StaticResource BorderStyleView}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

            <!-- StackLayout or Grid does not have an impact -->
            <StackLayout>
                <SearchBar ios:SearchBar.SearchBarStyle="Minimal" Text="{Binding SearchText}" Placeholder="{loc:Translate FoodsOverview_SearchFoodItemPlaceholder}"/>

                <CollectionView x:Name="InnerCollectionView" ItemsSource="{Binding GroupedFoodItems, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource CollectionViewStyle}" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand">

                </CollectionView>
            </StackLayout>
            
        </Border>
    </Grid>
    
</Grid>
```

Unfortunately, it does not stretch the Border to the bottom and I do not understand why?

Well, an answer could be that the Height of the CollectionView or the Border itself is too small.

But, I am asking myself if this is the case, why doesn't it strech out? Also, if this is the case, is there a way to stretch it to the bottom having a small white area like 25 or so between the Bottom and the CollectionView without providing a fixed size for it?

[image]

===== As requested in comment added red part for StackLayout =====

[image]

===== Using Grid with Layout Star =====

I previously also tried with a Layout using "Auto, *" but then it stretches out too much and not just to the bottom, as can be seen by the missing rounded corners at the bottom of the Border:

```xml
<Grid RowDefinitions="Auto, *">

    <Image x:Name="BackgroundImage" Source="backgroundimage.png" Aspect="AspectFill" />
    <Grid BackgroundColor="Transparent">
        <Grid.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1">
                <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0.1" />
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1.0" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Grid.Background>
    </Grid>

    <Grid Background="Green">
        <Border x:Name="InnerBorder" Style="{StaticResource BorderStyleView}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

            <!-- StackLayout or Grid does not have an impact -->
            <StackLayout Background="Red">
                <SearchBar ios:SearchBar.SearchBarStyle="Minimal" Text="{Binding SearchText}" Placeholder="{loc:Translate FoodsOverview_SearchFoodItemPlaceholder}"/>

                <CollectionView x:Name="InnerCollectionView" ItemsSource="{Binding GroupedFoodItems, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource CollectionViewStyle}" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand">

                </CollectionView>
            </StackLayout>

        </Border>
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

[image]

Same when using a Grid.RowSpan="2". The effect should be stacking of the elements "BackgroundImage" -> "LinearGradient" -> "Grid with CollectionView"

```xml
<Grid RowDefinitions="Auto, *">

    <Image x:Name="BackgroundImage" Grid.Row="0"  Source="backgroundimage.png" Aspect="AspectFill" />
    <Grid BackgroundColor="Transparent"  Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1">
                <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0.1" />
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1.0" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Grid.Background>
    </Grid>

    <Grid Background="Green"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <Border x:Name="InnerBorder" Style="{StaticResource BorderStyleView}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

            <!-- StackLayout or Grid does not have an impact -->
            <StackLayout Background="Red">
                <SearchBar ios:SearchBar.SearchBarStyle="Minimal" Text="{Binding SearchText}" Placeholder="{loc:Translate FoodsOverview_SearchFoodItemPlaceholder}"/>

                <CollectionView x:Name="InnerCollectionView" ItemsSource="{Binding GroupedFoodItems, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource CollectionViewStyle}" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand">

                </CollectionView>
            </StackLayout>

        </Border>
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

[image]

===== Parent of the ContentView with the elements above =====

```xml
<!-- We need two Grids to have space for the BottomSheet at the very bottom -->
<Grid IgnoreSafeArea="True">

    <Grid RowDefinitions="*, 55" VerticalOptions="End">
        
        <!--Switcher to switch between the different Views-->
        <tabs:ViewSwitcher x:Name="Switcher"
                           Animate="True"
                           Grid.Row="0"                               
                           SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedViewModelIndex, Mode=TwoWay}"
                           Margin="0, 0, 0, 105">

            <tabs:DelayedView x:TypeArguments="views:CalculateView"
                            BindingContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource CalculateViewModel}}"
                            AccentColor="{StaticResource Gray100}"
                            Animate="True"                              
                            UseActivityIndicator="True" />

            <tabs:DelayedView x:TypeArguments="views:OverviewView"
                            BindingContext="{Binding Source={viewModels:OverviewViewModel}}"
                            AccentColor="{StaticResource Gray100}"
                            Animate="True"
                            UseActivityIndicator="True" />

        </tabs:ViewSwitcher>

        
        
        <!--Tabs at the Bottom-->
        <tabs:TabHostView x:Name="TabHost"
                          Grid.Row="1"
                          BackgroundColor="White"
                          Orientation="Horizontal"
                          TabType="Fixed"
                          SelectedIndex="{Binding Source={x:Reference Switcher}, Path=SelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay}">

            <tabs:TabHostView.Tabs>
                <tabs:BottomTabItem Style="{StaticResource BottomTab}"
                                    IconImageSource="house_solid.png"
                                    Label="{loc:Translate AppShell_Calculate}"
                                    Margin="5, 0, 0, 0"/>

                <tabs:TabButton x:Name="CalculateCircleButton"
                                BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                ButtonCircleSize="110"
                                IconImageSource="circle.png"
                                TapCommand="{Binding Source={StaticResource  CalculateViewModel}, Path=DisplayBottomSheetCommand}"
                                TranslationY="-15" />


                <tabs:BottomTabItem Style="{StaticResource BottomTab}"
                                    IconImageSource="whole_solid.png"
                                    Label="{loc:Translate AppShell_Overview}" />

            </tabs:TabHostView.Tabs>
        </tabs:TabHostView>

    </Grid>

    
    
    <controls:BottomSheet x:Name="BottomSheet"
                          HeaderText="{loc:Translate BottomSheet_AddToHeader}"                              
                          BottomSheetClosed="BottomSheet_Closed"
                          SheetHeight="600"
                          InputTransparent="True">

        <!--The content of the BottomSheet is defined in an own View-->
        <controls:BottomSheet.BottomSheetContent>
            <views:BottomSheetContentView BindingContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource CalculateViewModel}}" />
        </controls:BottomSheet.BottomSheetContent>

    </controls:BottomSheet>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Set a background color on the element that border wraps. (Currently , StackLayout). So you can see it’s height. Then search for early questions about a layout not reaching to bottom of screen. Grid with rowdefinition star is the usual solution.

Comment: Copied your code to a page and you can see it stretched to full height, so maybe check your other content on your ContentPage (not this ContentView). And about bottom margin, in what circumstances do you think fixed size won't work, or do you mean safe area on ios

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve - see additional comment in original question which shows what I did

Comment: @Shaw - I suspect that as you mentioned the problem could be located in the parent of the ContentView containing all my elements from the code above. I think I need to have it as "*" in the RowDefinitions as the ContentView so that the ContentView that are switched can enlarge as needed: ```<Grid RowDefinitions="*, 55" VerticalOptions="End"> ... </Grid>```. But this might in the end be the problem that it can enlarge too much?

Comment: The 55 is the size of the Sharpnado Bottom-TabBar. Above there is the ViewSwitcher which actually displays the Views. As said, when I do it as "Auto, 55", I get a crash. I do not want to set a fixed size as this is a difficult topic handling different display sizes. So, I ended up setting it to "*, 55". But, I guess it is the problem that the Child-ContentView which is the code I postet in my original question might enlarge too much. Is there something that I could to to restrict it to the available height and not enlarge it too much?

Comment: Try a simple page without a custom component: `<ContentPage> <Grid RowDefinitions="*"> <Border> <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Red">` - stretch? What about with inner Grid: `<ContentPage> <Grid RowDefinitions="*"> <Border> <Grid RowDefinitions="*" BackgroundColor="Red">`? [Determining whether this is a limitation of how StackLayout behaves: it doesn't consume "*".]

Comment: I had to remove the Margin from the MainPage and did as you proposed using a Grid with RowDefinitions="*". It seems to be working now and streches correctly. The effect I wanted was that the stretched part stretches a bit further down so that this lower part is covered actually, which means the rounded bottom corners of the Border are not visible anymore. This I could realize with a ```<Grid Padding="0, 0, 0, -25">...</Grid>``` in the outer grid. Will see if a "-25" is a good idea when going from Portait to Landscape orientation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a small demo according to your code in your post and tried to reproduce the issue that Border does not stretch to bottom. However, your code works well on my side. And I think you are using [ContentView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/contentview) which enables the creation of custom, reusable controls.

1. Define the Define the UI of BorderContent.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiTest.Control.BorderContent">

    <ContentView.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="BorderStyleView" TargetType="Border">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource White}" />
                <Setter Property="StrokeShape" Value="RoundRectangle 10, 10, 10, 10" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="15" />
                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.9" />
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="Start"/>
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="CollectionViewStyle" TargetType="CollectionView">
                <Setter Property="IsGrouped" Value="True" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Always" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10, 5, 10, 15" />
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentView.Resources>


    <Grid>

        <Image Source="dotnet_bot.png" Aspect="AspectFill" />
        <Grid BackgroundColor="Transparent">
            <Grid.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1">
                    <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0.1" />
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1.0" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Grid.Background>
        </Grid>

        <Grid Background="Green">
            <Border x:Name="InnerBorder" Style="{StaticResource BorderStyleView}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

                <!-- StackLayout or Grid does not have an impact -->
                <StackLayout>
                    <SearchBar  Text="{Binding SearchText}" Placeholder="FoodsOverview_SearchFoodItemPlaceholder"/>

                    <CollectionView x:Name="InnerCollectionView" ItemsSource="{Binding GroupedFoodItems, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource CollectionViewStyle}" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand">

                    </CollectionView>
                </StackLayout>

            </Border>
        </Grid>

    </Grid>
</ContentView>
```

2. Instantiate a custom control

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MauiTest.Control"
             x:Class="MauiCursorTest.NewPage"
             Title="NewPage">

    <controls:BorderContent/>

</ContentPage>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your example. Maybe the base of the problem is in the Parent ContentView that is containing the ContentView with my elements from my original question. I added the code to my original question. There I do have a RowDefinitions with "*,55" and the idea was to let the ContentView take the size it needs. When I change to "Auto, 55" for instance it also crashes

Comment: If you read the comment in previous question, do you have an idea how I could restrict the parent height to get the effect you got?

Comment: Can you try to bind the Border's height to its parent Grid's actual height? Similarly, you can refer to [How to constrain a View's Width to its Height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75717286/how-to-constrain-a-views-width-to-its-height)

Comment: Do you think in the ContentView of the child containing the Border? Do you think a code like ```protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
{
    base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);

    if (height > 0)
    {
        InnerBorder.HeightRequest = height * 1.2;
    }
}``` would be considered problematic when I need the gap (similar to a Margin) anyway?

Comment: 1. I was intended that you could refer to [the posted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75730249/9644964). 2. If you are using Auto.*, consider [Disable the safe area layout guide on iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/platform-specifics/page-safe-area-layout). 3. Based on your code, I can't reproduce your issue, please help  create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and add it to your post.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was referring to. In the posted answer the WidthRequest is just bound to the Height of the parent Grid, which is okay. But in my case, I this does not solve the issue as I have overlays with the Background, LinearGradient and also the Border stacked in Grid.Row="0". To extend the Grid for the Border there was a 2nd Row in the parent Grid which is "*" in combination with Grid.RowSpan="2". This actually extends to much. But using just 1 row that is "Auto" for instance would not stack all 3 elements (BackgroundImage, LinearGradient and Border) correctly, Border not extending

Comment: Strangely enough, I deleted my code from my MainPage.xaml and inserted the code of my ContentView as you did but not with same result that would show it like in your screenshot :(

Comment: Yes, it's a bit weird, the ContentView should work as expected on your side.

Comment: I got the feeling, I should really try to solve what I wanted without any code in OnSizeAllocated(…) or comparable and code like HeightRequest = … * 1.2 or something like that. Below the green area is a Sharonado Tab and I wanted to have the Border go down slightly behind it. Before, I worked with multiplication to stretch it out (depending on portrait or landscape orientation). But, I think now that working with a Padding of like -25 is better? What do you think? Could work better on different display sizes?

Comment: Yes, the green area could be occupied by the Sharonado Tab.  Setting a Padding of like -25 is a better option for your scenario.

Comment: Thanks for confirming being on the right track then ☺️ And thank you very much for all your effort, help and sharing advice!

Comment: No worries, it's good to talk with you, man!